# Integrating over the region contained by the unit disk.

Tags: calculus

I am learning how to use double and triple integration;

I have some questions.

To find the area of some region $\Omega$ we integrate 1 with respect to both $x$ and $y$. If $\Omega$ is the region bounded by the unit circle we have;

$$\int^1_0\int^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}dydx = \pi/2$$ and not $$\int^1_{-1}\int^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}dydx = \pi$$

I would have thought $x$ ranges from -1 to 1? and indeed my answers confirm this, unless I went wrong somewhere in my calculations.

The reasoning behind this, is that in the text I am referring to, to learn the material says that the area of the region bounded by the curve is the first double integral.

Comment: What is the exact text of the problem?

Comment: Just having trouble understanding how the area of the unit disk is $\pi /2$ and not $\pi$

Comment: Are you given the first integral, then, just as it is written? If so, that won't give you the area of the unit disk, which most certainly has an area of $\pi$.

Comment: It is given as $\int^1_0\int^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}fdydx $, but f = 1, is a function. and by the definition gives the integral over the region. Which in this case (what the text has given) is the area of the half disk.

Comment: It seems to me that there is no question here: you are right when saying that the area of the unit disk is $\pi$, and that the outer integral should be $\int \limits _{-1} ^1 \dots \Bbb d x$. The book is right when it says that $\int \limits _0 ^1 \dots \Bbb d x = \frac \pi 2$, and it is the area of the region bounded by the upper half-circle and the $Ox$ axis (i.e. the half-disk). Everybody is right here, it seems to be only a misunderstanding.